# About Golang pointer,Why is that?

Tags: go

What happened ?

```
var n interface{} = 2
var pn = &n
var pf = (*int64)(unsafe.Pointer(pn))
fmt.Println(pf)
fmt.Println(pn)
fmt.Println(*pn) // 2
fmt.Println(*pf) // not 2
*pf = 9
fmt.Println(*pn) //error invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
fmt.Println(*pf) // 9
```

My question is Why is *pf not equal to *pn and error ?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: 1. Using fmt.Println is a bad idea to inspect variables as fmt.Println does not treat all argument types equal (e.g. it obviously unwraps interface{} values). 2. Using package unsafe is a sure recipe for disaster: It makes nonsense like *pf=9 possible, subverts any guaranties and your fault manifests in a nil pointer dereference.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `n` is of an `interface{}` type, so in memory it is represented by a struct of 2 values: a type and data. The type comes first. So you dereference it and interpret as a number.
2. `*pf = 9` breaks that structure, so next time you try to dereference it - the runtime fails.

Comment: I'd recommend the OP to read the classic ["Go Data Structures: Interfaces"](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces). It's a bit outdated (the Go runtime no longer embeds integer values of size ≤ `uintptr` directly into interface values) but still covers the implementation of interfaces very well.

Comment: thanks, I will be read [Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity let’s think we have 64-bit machine. 
`n` is pair of 2 words of 64-bit: first is a pointer to a variable, second is a pointer to information about type - so called `itab`.

When you get a value pointed by `pn` compiler knows you want value of an interface, so it goes by the first pointer and returns int value. Compiler thinks `pf` is a pointer to `float64` . So it lets. You to overwrite first word in the interface `n` with some likely incorrect address (equal to binary value of `9.0`). Next time you see the value in the interface compiler uses incorrect address. And return some garbage or even SegFault.

That’s why it’s called `unsafe.Pointer` and is not recommended to use. Until you have *very serious* concerns.

Answer (score 0):

An interface value contains information about the type of the data it contains and then the actual value (or a pointer to the value). When you cast a pointer to the interface to `*int64`, the `*int64` will point into some random data in the interface value (which today happens to be a pointer to the information about the type, but this is allowed to change, this part of the language is not covered by the compatibility guarantee). When you then overwrite that data, things break, unsafe is called unsafe for a reason.

`*pf` is not equal to `*pn` because they have different types even though they might contain the same bit pattern.